# choose a point with uniform distribution in a triangle $(0,1),(0,0),(1,0)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, density-function

We choose a point with uniform distribution in a triangle $(0,1),(0,0),(1,0)$. Calculate $Cov(X,Y)$. In the solution they stated that:
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{0.5}I_{\{0<y<1,y<1-x,0<x<1\}}
$$
I'm a bit confused about $I$. Is it an indicator? What does it represents here? why ${\{0<y<1,y<1-x,0<x<1\}}$ and which formula did they use to calculate it? I guess it's the base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that notation is an indicator function.  Sometimes written with $I$, or my preference, $\mathbb 1$, it is simply $$\mathbb 1_{(x,y) \in S} = \begin{cases}1, & (x,y) \in S \\ 0, & (x,y) \not\in S \end{cases}$$ where $S$ is some set.  Then, we can characterize the points inside this triangle with vertices $(0,1), (0,0), (1,0)$ as those points $(x,y)$ satisfying the simultaneous inequalities $$0 < x < 1 \\ 0 < y < 1 \\ x + y < 1.$$  In fact, this specification is a bit redundant:  the edge joining $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ is attained with only the inequality $y > 0$; the edge joining $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$ is attained with $x > 0$; and the last edge joining $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ is given by $x + y < 1$.  No other inequalities are needed.

We can then use this to write the indicator in other ways; e.g., we could write it as $$\mathbb 1_{\{x > 0\}} \mathbb 1_{\{y > 0\}} \mathbb 1_{\{x+y < 1\}},$$ for example.

Note that the value of the density $f(x,y)$ in this triangular region must be $2$ because the area of the triangle is $1/2$.

As for the covariance, it is not difficult to compute $\operatorname{E}[XY]$, $\operatorname{E}[X]$, and $\operatorname{E}[Y]$.  The latter two must be equal due to symmetry of $X$ and $Y$ on the joint support.

Comment: given two points $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ how do you know its inequality? Also which formula did they use to calculate $f(x,y)$?

Comment: @abuka123 I will answer your question with a question:  on which side of the line joining $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ does the triangle lie?  That determines the direction of the inequality.  As for your other question, I already stated the answer.  If $X, Y$ are jointly uniform in some region with area $A$, then the joint density $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 1/A$ for all $(x,y)$ in the support of $X, Y$.

Comment: lets say $(0,b)$ where $b>0$ and $(c,0)$ where $c>0$. I just don't get why $x+y<1$

Comment: @abuka123 $x+y = 1$ is the equation of the line passing through $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$.  In the general case, the line passing through $(0,b)$ and $(c,0)$ is $x/c + y/b = 1$.  Therefore, the triangle joining these points with the origin will obey the inequalities $x > 0$, $y > 0$, $x/c + y/b < 1$.  And the area of this triangle is $bc/2$, thus the density has value $2/(bc)$ in this region.